# How can I upload photos in struts 2 into my public_html directory instead of my tomcat's directory?

Tags: servlets, file-upload, save

When uploading `1-6969875-2644-t.jpg`, the image is uploaded to
 `/home/xrcwrn/jvm/apache-tomcat-6.0.14/domains/xyz.com/ROOT/img/1-6969875-2644-t.jpg` properly.

But I actually want to upload this image into the `/home/xrcwrn/public_html/img` folder.

I am using this code in Struts 2:

```
public String execute() {

    try {
        ServletContext servletContext = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
        String path =servletContext.getRealPath("/img");
        System.out.println("Server path:" + path);
        String filePath = servletContext.getRealPath(path);
        File uploadDir = new File(filePath);
        String relPath = uploadDir.getAbsolutePath();
        //if the folder does not exits, creating it
        if (uploadDir.exists() == false) {
            uploadDir.mkdirs();
        }
        File fileToCreate = new File(path, this.userImageFileName);
        FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
        String pt = path + "/" + getUserImageFileName();
        System.out.println("image path is :" + pt);
        setImagePath(pt);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        addActionError(e.getMessage());
        return INPUT;
    }
    System.out.println(" **************inside image upload***********");

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `ServletContext#getRealPath()`. You don't want to write uploaded files to there. They will get lost whenever you redeploy the webapp or even when you restart the server.

Replace

```
String path =servletContext.getRealPath("/img");
System.out.println("Server path:" + path);
String filePath = servletContext.getRealPath(path);
```

by

```
String filePath = "/home/xrcwrn/public_html/img";
```

If you want to make this configureable, consider providing it as a system property or a properties file setting.